# Fullscreen image - but keep navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fullscreen background image. I can do this but the problem, however, is that I cannot keep my top/navigation bar.

It's a template but I've made much different.

I'm quite new to HTML / CSS, so please bear with me. How do I move on from this?

PS: The image fills the whole screen right now but there is a navigation bar beneath it - also an header image (logo)

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Adem Ökmen Photography</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="../layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body id="top">

    <!-- Top Background Image Wrapper -->
    <div class="bgded2" style="background-image:url('../images/demo/backgrounds/adem%20black.png');">

      <header id="header" class="hoc clear">
        <div id="logo">
          <h1><i class="fa" > </i> <a href="../index.html"></a></h1>
        </div>
        <!--navi bar-->
        <nav id="mainav" class="fl_left">
          <ul class="clear">
            <!--"Hjem" tab-->
            <li><a href="../index.html">Hjem</a></li>
            <!--Galleri tab-->
            <li class="active"><a class="drop" href="gallery.html">Galleri</a>
              <ul>
                <!--"#" er link  ... drop down-->
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Udvalgte</a></li>
                <li><a href="wedding.html">Bryllup</a></li>
                <li><a href="portrait.html">Portræt</a></li>
                <li><a href="outside.html">Udendørs</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="partyPrice.html">Festfotografering priser </a></li>
            <li><a href="portrait1.html">Portrætfotografering priser</a></li>
            <li><a href="printPrice.html">Priser på billedprint</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

    </div>
    </div>

    <header id="imageFull" class="hoc clear">
      <!--navi bar -->
      <nav id="mainav2" class="fl_left">
        <ul class="clear">
          <div id="bg">
            <img src="../images/demo/gallery/Amnah-2.jpg">
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
    <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
    <!-- IE9 Placeholder Support -->
    <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
    <!--/ IE9 Placeholder Support -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's a part of my CSS enter code here;

```
#bg {
position: fixed;
top: -50%;
left: -50%;
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: try `background-image` for `body` then `background-size` 100%

Comment: You have an extra closing `</div>` above the second header. Not sure if this is related to your problem, but you should remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your background need to be on body or some element above the navigation.
Second - try to not use position fixed on background image(use background-attachment:fixed)

So you might do it like this:

```css
body{
  background: silver url(...) no-repeat;/*remove silver and fill the proper url*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

nav{
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      Some navigation here...
    </nav>
    Header section here....
  </header>
  body section here....
</body>
```

With `background-attachment: fixed` when u scroll the background-image will remain static and only the content will scroll.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your code your setting the background image to the wrong div. Perhaps make the `background-image` part of the `html` or `body` CSS instead. That way your nav bar *should* be able to appear correctly too.

Hope this helps:)